# call another method of `self` in a thread started in method of `self` in rust

Tags: rust, struct, thread-safety, borrow-checker

got this relatively simple code

```
use std::thread;


struct Runner {
    data: String
}

impl Runner {
    fn new(s: &str) -> Self {
        Self { data: s.to_owned() }
    }

    fn doit(&mut self) {
        // modify `self.data`
    }

    fn run(&mut self) {

        for _ in 0..4 {
            thread::spawn(move ||{
               self.doit(); 
            });
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut r = Runner::new("hello");
    r.run();
}
```

and it doesn't compile since I am moving `self` and I completely understand why.
but what can I do in order to achieve the wanted behavior?

I wanna be able to change `data` from the running threads. so I actually need `Mutex` for the whole `self` thing.

how can this be achieved? is there another idiomatic way to do so?

Comment: Well, what is the wanted behavior? Do you want to wait for the threads or not? How do you ensure the lack of data races?

Answer (score 2):

try using [std::sync::Arc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html) (thread-safe reference-counting pointer) with Mutex for protecting shared data:

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Runner {
    data: String,
}

impl Runner {
    fn new(s: &str) -> Self {
        Self { data: s.to_owned() }
    }

    fn doit(&mut self) {
        // modify `self.data`
        self.data.push_str(".w");
    }

    fn run(r: &Arc<Mutex<Runner>>) {
        let mut handles = vec![];
        for _ in 0..4 {
            let rc = Arc::clone(r);

            let h = thread::spawn(move || {
                rc.lock().unwrap().doit();
                dbg!(rc);
            });

            handles.push(h);
        }

        for h in handles {
            h.join().unwrap();
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let r = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Runner::new("hello")));
    Runner::run(&r);
}
```

[Slightly modified version](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1de83b3743f0d808f7fd52696bb58d71) with `&self` method instead of associated function.